# js добавление div к документу

Tags: javascript, jquery

привет есть код

```
function add()
        {
            var j = 0;
            setInterval(function ()
            {
                j++;
                var lef = getRandomFloat(100, 1200);
                $("body").append('<div class=' + j.toString() + '></div >');
                $('.' + j.toString() + '').css({"background-color": "#ffe", "height": "50px", "width": "50px" }).offset({ top: 0, left: lef });
            }, 1000);
        }
```

это типа в верху аппендит дивы но почему полоса прокрутки по вертикали появляется типа растет высота документа но ведь у них высота в ноль установлена.
В чем прикол
Если верить инспектору в хроме то параметр `top` у каждого следующего div увеличивается на 50. Откуда такое поведение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все просто оказалось я затупил с позиционированием

```
position:absolute;
```

Comment: Не классно менять столько стилей js'ом. Почему нельзя добавлять\удалять класс js'ом, а стили вынести в css?

Comment: это был черновой варинат сейчас уже все в сss вынес